# magento 1.9 | how setStockData on collection

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, product-collection

i have this code

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('SKU')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('modelnumber', $params['modelnumber'])
            ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id', '10')
            ->joinField(
                'qty',
                'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                'qty',
                'product_id=entity_id',
                '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                'left'
            )
            ->getFirstItem();

        $productCollection->setStockData(array(
                'use_config_manage_stock' => 1,
                'manage_stock'=>1,
                'is_in_stock' => 1,
                'qty' => 25
            )
        );

        $productCollection->save();
```

But i have error

```
 Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::setStockData()
```

How i can save stockData ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code,

```
$stockData = ['qty' => 25, 'is_in_stock' => 1];

     $productCollection->setStockData($stockData);
```

I hope its work for you.